# How can I set ripples (android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground") in a constraint.Group

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have a `contraint.Group` inside my *item_layout* that I will use it in a **recyclerView**:

```
<android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/constraintGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageView, textView" />
```

I also set the *onClickListener* for this group in the activity that works perfectly. The problem is that every time I tap on the group, the ripple effect isn't there.

***Anyone knows what should I do to have that effect in a constraint.Group?***

I tried adding the attribute `android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"` to the parent and the constraint.Group but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

A `Group` is only for controlling visibility. You cannot control arbitrary UI attributes of the members of a group, such as the background. Instead, you would need to put your background on the actual widgets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) What do you mean with the actual widget?

Comment: @Noelia: In your sample code in the question, your `Group` consists of two widgets, with IDs of `imageView` and `textView`. You need to put your background on those widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using androidx.constraintLayout.widget.Group. It is an updated version of android.support.constraint.Group.

The following code adds the ripple effect

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```